# Using different Epilog for multiple plots with PlotLayout

Tags: plotting

I would like to generate several plots like in my example, but use a different `Epilog` for each plot.

```
ContourPlot[{Sin[x] + Cos[y], (x)^2 - (y)^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLayout -> "Row"
 , Epilog -> {
   {Thickness[Large], Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 1.5]},
   {Thickness[Large], Blue, Circle[{0, 0}, 0.5]}
   }
 ]
```

[image]

I'd like to have one circle on the left plot, the other circle on the right plot.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
deleteUnwantedEpilogs = 
  Module[{pos = Position[#, HoldPattern[Epilog -> _], All]},
    Delete[#, Apply[Join] @
      MapIndexed[((x |-> Join[#, {2}, {x}]) /@ 
           Drop[Range@Length@pos, #2]) &] @ pos]] &;
```

***Examples:***

```
cp = ContourPlot[{Sin[x] + Cos[y], (x)^2 - (y)^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
 PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLayout -> "Row"
 , Epilog -> {
   {Thickness[Large], Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 1.5]},
   {Thickness[Large], Blue, Circle[{0, 0}, 0.5]}
   }
 ];

deleteUnwantedEpilogs @ cp
```

[image]

```
deleteUnwantedEpilogs @
 ContourPlot[{Sin[x] + Cos[y], (x)^2 - (y)^2, Sin[x y]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
  PlotLegends -> Automatic, PlotLayout -> "Row", 
  Epilog -> {{Thickness[Large], Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 1.5]}, 
    {Thickness[Large], Blue, Circle[{0, 0}, 0.5]}, 
    {Thickness[Large], Green, Circle[{0, 0}, 0.25]}}]
```

[image]

Replace `Epilog -> ...` with

```
Epilog -> 
 {{Thickness[Large], Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 1.5], Purple,  Circle[{0, 0}, .75]}, 
  {Thickness[Large], Blue, Circle[{0, 0}, 0.5], Magenta, Rectangle[{.5, .5}]}, 
  {Thickness[Large], Green, Circle[{0, 0}, 0.25], Cyan, Circle[{0, 0}, 1.25]}}
```

to get

[image]

Comment: Cool, generate all Epilogs and delete the unwanted ones later. I'll happily accept that!

Answer (score 3):

```
Clear["Global`*"]

Legended[
 GraphicsGrid[
  {ContourPlot[#[[1]],
      {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2},
      Epilog -> {Thickness[Large], #[[2]], Circle[{0, 0}, #[[3]]]},
      ImagePadding -> #[[4]]] & /@ {
     {Sin[x] + Cos[y], Red, 1.5, Automatic},
     {x^2 - y^2, Blue, 0.5, {{0., 28.7192}, {-1., 25.8194}}}}},
  Spacings -> 0],
 BarLegend[{"WL13DefaultDensityGradient", {-4, 4}}]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Something like:

```
epi1 = {Thickness[Large], Red, Circle[{0, 0}, 1.5]};
epi2 = {Thickness[Large], Blue, Circle[{0, 0}, 0.5]};

Row[{ContourPlot[{Sin[x] + Cos[y]}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 200, BoundaryStyle -> Black,
    Epilog -> epi1],
  ContourPlot[{(x)^2 - (y)^2}, {x, -2, 2}, {y, -2, 2}, 
   PlotLegends -> Automatic, ImageSize -> 200, BoundaryStyle -> Black,
    Epilog -> epi2]
  }]
```

[image]

Comment: This creates to separate axes and two separate legends, which I tried to avoid. With PlotLayout, I'll get the same legend for both plots and a common color scale